# When initially connecting to REST API with SSL, NSURLConnection load will fail on occasion

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlconnection

I am working on an iOS app that connects to a REST API, and recently wanted it to connect using SSL, so I changed the url and also added in some additional methods so that it would be able to. However, it will oftentimes error out initially, then will have no further issues. Can anyone see any obvious errors within the code below?

Here is the error that shows up:
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Code is below:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {

    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)load:(NSData*)data completionHandler:(void(^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error))handler

{
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Loading... %@", s);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody:data];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue

                           completionHandler:handler];

    [urlConnection start];
}
```

Comment: is your web server configured with trusted ssl certificate or with self-signed?

Comment: It's a trusted certificate (Go Daddy).